Is shadow always small in variance shadow mapping?
I have a question of variance shadow mapping I made in my program whether that is well-made or not.
Suppose scene is like below image, because of directional light, region below of cube 1 in cube 2 and plane must be shadowed.
supposed scene
In vsm I made in my program, however, that isn't fully shadowed despite of cube 1's and cube 2's size, position of x, z is same.
rendering of supposed scene
Is this situation natural in vsm?
I think this situation is natural because distribution of depth using in vsm is constructed by cube 1's and plane's depth, not cube 2's depth. And in point of light view, mean of surrounding depths is increased from center of cube 1 to edge of cube 1.
 So In edge of cube 2, because of mean of surrounding depths is larger than depth of cube 2, it isn't shadowed.
 Is this thinking right? I post question because i don't have confidence of it.

In addition, when increase vsm filter size, size of shadow is decreased. Could I think context of this is same with above situation?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
